# Call ajax from any folder

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am running an asp.net website with an ajax call.  However, I can't get the call to work when in a subfolder.

What I want to have happen is one place to define the ajax call:

```
function LogOut() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Services/wsvc_Security.asmx/LogOut",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) { console.log("done"); },
        error: function (request, errorType, errorMessage) { console.log('ajax error - ' + request + '\n' + errorMessage); }
    });
}
```

The problem arises when in the /admin folder ... it can't find my services folder in the root.  Yes, I could use /Services/wsvc_Security.asmx/LogOut ... except that on the server I have 2 application paths:  /LiveVersion and /TestVersion.  I don't want to have to change code when deploying to different environments.

Is there a way to do in javascript what I can do in .Net?  meaning:  ~/Services/wsvc_Security.asmx/LogOut

Where ~/ gets me the root of the application

Comment: How about you put the actual path to `LogOut` in the ajax instead of trying to use some "relative" magic?

Comment: If I put the actual path, then every time I deploy it to live or test from development, I would have to change ALL of my ajax calls (I have at least 50 in different scrdipts)?  This is what I'm trying to avoid.  

url:  "http://localhost/developmentfolder/Servers/wsvc_Security.asmx/LogOut"

url:  "http://prodserver/application/Servers/wsvc_Security.asmx/LogOut"

url:  "http://testserver/application/Servers/wsvc_Security.asmx/LogOut"

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this would be to have different configs for live and test version. For each of the 2, you could have a root defined differently i.e. in test config, say `root = 'live/something'` and on test `root = 'test/something'`.
So you'd call the url as 
`url: root + "Services/wsvc_Security.asmx/LogOut"`

PS. Bear this in mind that the configs should be seperate for test and live

Comment: this could be an option as I do have one /Scripts/site.js file that is loaded in the master page and it loaded before other page scripts.  I was really hoping that was some slick way to do it like ASP.NET's:   ~/ option of making it relative to the project regardless of folder/subfolders